# Как тестировать чтение файлов

Tags: node.js, testng

У меня есть начальный маршрут.

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express();
const not_found = path.join(__dirname, './views/email_templates/not_found.html');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(
        fs.readFileSync(
            not_found, {
                encoding: 'utf-8'
            }
        )
    );
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

export { server, admin };

export default router;
```

Я написал для него тест.

```
describe('Index', () => {
    describe('GET /', () => {
        it(`Should return page not found`, (done) => {
            chai
                .request(server)
                .get('/')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(res).have.status(200);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Как я понимаю этого не достаточно. Как мне протестировать `fs.readFileSync`, что пришел `html` файл?